# WSO2 Identiy Server SAML SSO Request

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server, wso2-asgardeo

I am using WSO2 Identity server SAML2.0 authentitcation
I am using asgardeo library (it is working fine when authentication method is **opid connect**)
What will be SAML2 SSO request URL and how we consume it.

By using
https://serverIP:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=IssureName
and
https://serverIP:9443/samlsso

I am getting below response

**SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
Error when processing authentication request!
Please try login again!**

In my thought I need a valid url...please help

I have download the code form given below URL (I know it is DEPRECATED) but  I can't use asgardeo server
https://github.com/wso2-attic/asgardeo-dotnet-oidc-sdk

I am implementing it c#

Please HELP...............Thanks In Advance

https://github.com/wso2-attic/asgardeo-dotnet-oidc-sdk

Comment: what is the IS version?

Comment: my IS version is  5.11